# Managed package governor limits

Tags: managed-package, governorlimits

We have a managed package that we don't want to publish to App Exchange.
Is there any way that we can get our separate governor limits, so our operations wouldn't count against the installing organization limits?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Refer 'Per-Transaction Certified Managed Package Limits' section in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

> Certified managed packages—managed packages that have passed the
>   security review for AppExchange—get their own set of limits for most
>   per-transaction limits. Certified managed packages are developed by
>   Salesforce ISV Partners, are installed in your org from Salesforce
>   AppExchange, and have unique namespaces.

Possible duplicate of https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008uIDIAY

Comment: yes, but if I publish it as a private app, and go over security review? Is it enough or it must be public?

Comment: @MeravBenPaz you don't have to list it on app exchange, i.e. it can be private but still be a certified managed package.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get around to this earlier. @PhilHawthorn is right :)